# docker ps --all not showing old containers in docker compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am running two docker container using docker compose.

Here is my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3'

services:
    redis-server:
        image: 'redis'
    node-app:
        build: .
        ports:
            - "4001:8081"
```

And after running the command `docker-compose up`, docker is creating two container **redis-server** and **node-app** as we can see in the image below:

[image]

I added **restart policy** for **node-app** service in `docker-compose.yml` as shown below:

```
version: '3'

services:
    redis-server:
        image: 'redis'
    node-app:
        restart: on-failure
        build: .
        ports:
            - "4001:8081"
```

And when I run the `docker-compose up` again, the containers are created again. Here is the output `docker ps --all`:

[image]

I see that container id for **node-app** is different between two executions which is due to the fact that docker is creating a new container. But my question is why can't I see the old container for **node-app** that was created during the first execution (container id: 96b19ffca388) when I type `docker ps --all` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Docker-Compose is smart and will automatiaclly stop your old containers and re-create them with your updates when you run `Docker-Compose up`. From the [official documentation page](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/compose_up/):

> If there are existing containers for a service, and the service’s configuration or image was changed after the container’s creation, docker compose up picks up the changes by stopping and recreating the containers (preserving mounted volumes). To prevent Compose from picking up changes, use the --no-recreate flag

Answer (score 0):

Because they are no longer there. When `docker-compose` restarted it cleaned up after itself. This can be verified quite easily. If you run in the machine that runs the compose: `ps -ef | grep <container id>` for a one of the newer containers you will see it is there, whereas running the same command for one of the old ones will find nothing. Those containers aren't paused, they're deleted.